# Creation of Protobuf schema from JSON Schema classes without using annotations in quakrus

Tags: infinispan

Is there any option for Creation of  Protobuf schema from JSON Schema classes without using annotaitons for infinispan cache in quakrus

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it's not the recommended way of Quarkus. You can disable the schema upload in the server (quarkus.infinispan-client.use-schema-registration=false), do it from your side using the hotrod client, cli, rest, the console...
on the client side you can add a marshaller yourself https://quarkus.io/guides/infinispan-client#custom-serialization